# Why can't I still directly call method in sub-contract of basic-contract-caller example after removing method that allows calling from main contract?

Tags: ink, cross-contract-call, basic-contract-caller

In [this commit of this Pull Request](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/ed4290e1fc13624388bd97a2fcee9c4f1a3296d0) I'm using a modified version of this [ink! basic-contract-caller example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/basic_contract_caller) where there is a BasicContractCaller main contract and a OtherContract sub-contract.

To run it, I follow the steps in the [README file](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/blob/unnamed/README.md#setup-docker-container-) and then after entering the Docker container I run `cd /app && ./docker/quickstart-basic-contract-caller.sh` and it runs through these steps without generating any errors:

0. Starts a fresh local node using substrate-contracts-node
1. Builds both of those contracts
2. Uploads both of those contracts
3. Instantiates both of those contracts
4. Calls a setter method `flip()` in the sub-contract directly `cargo contract call --suri //Alice --contract $CONTRACT_ADDR_SUB --message get --execute --gas 100000000000 --proof-size 100000000000 --skip-confirm`
5. Calls a getter method `get()` in the sub-contract directly with `cargo contract call --suri //Alice --contract $CONTRACT_ADDR_SUB --message get --execute --skip-confirm`
6. Calls a method `get()` in the main contract that calls a getter method `get()` in the sub-contract `cargo contract call --suri //Alice --contract $CONTRACT_ADDR_MAIN --message get --execute --skip-confirm`

But if I simply remove step 6. by removing the method/message `get()` from the main contract and comment out the code in the bash script that calls it, then when I run `./docker/quickstart-basic-contract-caller.sh` again it generates the following error:

```
ERROR: No constructor or message with the name 'get' found
```

So my question is, if I remove step 6. which involves removing the method `get()` from the main contract that is used to call `get()` method in the sub-contract [as shown in this subsequent commit that reproduces the error](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTemplate/pull/16/commits/931fe208737aca934a01768e75ff715e9ded3b53), how may I then still call the `get()` method in the sub-contract directly in step 5. without encountering this error?